# Check if two arrays have an object with the same property

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, iteration, comparison

**Here's my goal:**  compare two objects and figure out if there is 1 or more items in common. If there are 1 or more in common, return `true` otherwise (no items in common), return `false`.

**Current issues:**  I'm trying to use the `.some()` method with 1 object from an API and 1 object that's local, but a bit confused why it's not working...any ideas? It should return true since John is in both objects, but it returns false

**Code example:**  in this example, it should return `true` because John is a name that is both object 1 (result1) and object 2 (result 2). However, it returns `false`.

Is anyone able to help me understand what I'm doing wrong here?

```js
var result1 = [
        {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
        {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
        {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
        {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
    ];

var result2 = [
        {id:2, name:'John', email:'johnny@example.com'},
        {id:4, name:'Bobby', email:'bobby@example.com'}
    ];

const hasSimilarElement = result1.some((item) => item.name === result2.name); 

console.log(hasSimilarElement);
```

Comment: none of this is JSON, there is no such thing as a JSON object - JSON is a **string** - result2 is an Array, `result2.name` does can not equal "John" ... result2[0].name is John ... you need to iterate both Arrays to check if there is a match - perhaps `result1.some((item) => result2.some(item2 => item.name === item2.name));`

Comment: I mean ok, but can you help me understand why the value is false? Or can you help me understand why it's not iterating in the way I'm intending with `.some()` @Bravo ?

Comment: I did tell you why ... `result2.name` is not 'John' ... it's never a string, it's `undefined` because, unless you set a property called `name` on an Array, it has no such property - you only iterate result1, you are not iterating result2 - all this is said in the first comment

Comment: The OP needs to [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) an item with an equal `item.name` value of `result1` within `result2` instead of directly comparing a non existing (thus `undefined`) `name` property of `result2`.

Comment: @InterstellarX ... Regarding the so far provided answers / approaches / solutions are there any questions left?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a function that takes a function `f` to use for the lookup then two arrays `xs` & `ys`:

```js
const checkBy = f => (xs, ys) => {
  let [long, short] = xs.length > ys.length ? [xs, ys] : [ys, xs];
  short = new Set(short.map(f));
  return long.some(x => short.has(f(x)));
};
```

Then:

```js
const checkByName = checkBy(x => x.name);

checkByName( [ {id: 1, name:'Sandra', type:  'user', username:  'sandra'}
             , {id: 2, name:  'John', type: 'admin', username: 'johnny2'}
             , {id: 3, name: 'Peter', type:  'user', username:    'pete'}
             , {id: 4, name: 'Bobby', type:  'user', username:  'be_bob'}]

           , [ {id: 2, name:  'John', email: 'johnny@example.com'}
             , {id: 4, name: 'Bobby', email:  'bobby@example.com'}]);
//=> true

checkByName( [ {id: 1, name:'Sandra', type:  'user', username:  'sandra'}
             , {id: 2, name:  'John', type: 'admin', username: 'johnny2'}
             , {id: 3, name: 'Peter', type:  'user', username:    'pete'}
             , {id: 4, name: 'Bobby', type:  'user', username:  'be_bob'}]

           , [ {id: 2, name:  'xxxx', email: 'johnny@example.com'}
             , {id: 4, name: 'yyyyy', email:  'bobby@example.com'}]);
//=> false
```

Comment: ... technically the best approach/implementation so far, imho.

Comment: This is great, but the only advantage over the simpler `const overlap = (f) => (xs, ys, ks = new Set (xs .map (f))) => ys .some (y => ks .has (f (y)))` is that it can map `f` against the shorter list.  For many uses, I wouldn't bother with this optimization.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the technique proposed by customcommander for your exact scenario, and for anywhere you can extract a unique key from your objects as a primitive type.  (Here `name`s are strings, so that works.)

If you need something more generic, then you can supply a function that tells if two elements are equal and use it like this:

```js
const overlap = (equal) => (xs, ys) => 
  xs .some (x => ys .some (y => equal (x, y)))

const result1 = [{id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'}, {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'}, {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'}, {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}]
const result2 = [{id:2, name:'John', email:'johnny@example.com'}, {id:4, name:'Bobby', email:'bobby@example.com'}]

console .log (overlap ((x, y) => x .name == y .name) (result1, result2))
```

This is less efficient in those cases where you could generate a unique key, but it's more generic.  You can even use it for two arrays where the two arrays have objects with different structures, passing for instance `(x, y) => x .id == y .primaryKey`.

Comment: A user-supplied equality function is definitely the right way to go here. Don’t know why I didn’t think of that.

Comment: perfect answer 

Answer (score 0):

From the above comment ...

> *"The OP needs to [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) an item with an equal `item.name` value of `result1` within `result2` instead of directly comparing a non existing (thus `undefined`) `name` property of `result2`."*

Or as correctly suggested by *3limin4t0r* one could swap [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for another [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) again.

```js
const result1 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Sandra', type: 'user', username: 'sandra' },
  { id: 2, name: 'John', type: 'admin', username: 'johnny2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Peter', type: 'user', username: 'pete' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Bobby', type: 'user', username: 'be_bob' },
];
const result2 = [
  { id: 5, name: 'Lea', email: 'lea@example.com' },
  { id: 2, name: 'John', email: 'johnny@example.com' },
];

const result3 = [
  { id: 5, name: 'Lea', email: 'lea@example.com' },
];
const result4 = [];

console.log(
  'similar elements within `result1` and `result2` ..?',
  result1.some(itemA =>
    result2.some(itemB => itemB.name === itemA.name)
  )
);
console.log(
  'similar elements within `result1` and `result3` ..?',
  result1.some(itemA =>
    result3.some(itemB => itemB.name === itemA.name)
  )
);
console.log(
  'similar elements within `result1` and `result4` ..?',
  result1.some(itemA =>
    result4.some(itemB => itemB.name === itemA.name)
  )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Within a next iteration one of cause could come up with a generically implemented function which allows the to be compared property name to be freely chosen.

Implementing a function also gives the opportunity to get rid of the two nested `some` iterations (though `some` of cause exits early for a successful comparison).

Here one would build from the shorter array a `key` (property name) specific value-index (a single iteration task), where, while iterating the longer array, one would look up (no iteration) the `key` specific value for item similarity.

```js
function hasSimilarItemsByKey(key, arrA, arrB) {
  const [
    // the shorter array will be the base
    // for a `key` specific value index.
    lookupArray,
    // the longer array will be iterated
    // and have its item `key` specific 
    // values looked up at a value index.
    targetArray,
  ] = [
    arrA,
    arrB,
  ].sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);

  // create the object based value index
  // (from the shorter array).
  const valueIndex = lookupArray
    .reduce((lookup, item) => {

      const value = item[key];
      lookup[value] ??= value;

      return lookup;
    }, Object.create(null));  // A `prototype`-less object. Thus,
                              // using the `in` operator is safe.
  return targetArray.some(item => item[key] in valueIndex);
}

const result1 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Sandra', type: 'user', username: 'sandra' },
  { id: 2, name: 'John', type: 'admin', username: 'johnny2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Peter', type: 'user', username: 'pete' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Bobby', type: 'user', username: 'be_bob' },
];
const result2 = [
  { id: 5, name: 'Lea', email: 'lea@example.com' },
  { id: 2, name: 'John', email: 'johnny@example.com' },
];

const result3 = [
  // Attention,
  // A matching `id` and a non matching `name`.
  { id: 1, name: 'Lea', email: 'lea@example.com' },
];
const result4 = [];

console.log(
  'similar elements within `result1` and `result2`\n',
  '...by `name`..?', hasSimilarItemsByKey('name', result1, result2),
  '...by `id`..?', hasSimilarItemsByKey('id', result1, result2),
);
console.log(
  'similar elements within `result1` and `result3`\n',
  '...by `name`..?', hasSimilarItemsByKey('name', result1, result3),
  '...by `id`..?', hasSimilarItemsByKey('id', result1, result3),
);
console.log(
  'similar elements within `result1` and `result4`\n',
  '...by `name`..?', hasSimilarItemsByKey('name', result1, result4),
  '...by `id`..?', hasSimilarItemsByKey('id', result1, result4),
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: If, in addition to the voting, there was also a comment left about what deserved the downvote, I had the chance to improve the code and learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

> Array.prototype.some()
> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

In your example you are trying to compare 2 arrays of objects. You have false as result2.name is undefined, you might need to specify the index of an particular element e.g. result2[0].name

If you'd like to compare 2 arrays with some you need to iterate through result2 items as well. You can use somehting like this:

```
var result1 = [
        {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
        {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
        {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
        {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
    ];

var result2 = [
        {id:2, name:'John', email:'johnny@example.com'},
        {id:4, name:'Bobby', email:'bobby@example.com'}
    ];    
const hasSimilarElement = result2.filter((item1) => !result1.some(item2 => item1.name === item2.name ));

console.log(hasSimilarElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code fails is that you are trying to find a match for a `name` in the elements of result1 Array to `result2.name`

However, `result2` is also an `Array`, Array's do not have a `.name` that happens to be all of the elements `.name`s that somehow matches  the one you are searching for - that's not how it works

You need to iterate both Arrays to look for a match

```js
var result1 = [
        {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
        {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
        {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
        {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
    ];

var result2 = [
        {id:2, name:'John', email:'johnny@example.com'},
        {id:4, name:'Bobby', email:'bobby@example.com'}
    ];

const hasSimilarElement = result1.some((item) => result2.some(item2 => item.name === item2.name)); 

console.log(hasSimilarElement);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

However, for very large result sets this is inefficient - I'm no "big O notation expert, but I believe this would be O(n<sup>2</sup>) - you're potentially going to compare `result1.length` * `result2.length` times

For this simple case, you can extract just the `.name` from both results, and create a `Set` ... if the `Set` size is less than the combined result `.length`s it means there's a duplicate

here, you'll iterate each result once each - if both sets have 1000 elements that's 2,000 iterations, compared to 1,000,000 using the naive method above

```js
var result1 = [
        {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
        {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
        {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
        {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
    ];

var result2 = [
        {id:2, name:'John', email:'johnny@example.com'},
        {id:4, name:'Bobby', email:'bobby@example.com'}
    ];

const hasSimilarElement = new Set([...result1, ...result2].map(({name}) => name)).size < result1.length + result2.length
console.log(hasSimilarElement);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

However, there is a flawif there's a duplicate name within one of the results, this will not work as expected

Here each set is iterated twice - but, given 2 x 1,000 long results,  4,000 iterations is still better than 1,000,000

```js
var result1 = [
        {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
        {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
        {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
        {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
    ];

var result2 = [
        {id:2, name:'John', email:'johnny@example.com'},
        {id:4, name:'Bobby', email:'bobby@example.com'}
    ];

const set1 = new Set(result1.map(({name}) => name));
const set2 = new Set(result2.map(({name}) => name));
const both = new Set([...set1, ...set2]);
const hasSimilarElement = both.size < set1.size + set2.size;

console.log(hasSimilarElement);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I feel like you are overcomplicating things with the sets. You could just have a single set and use that in combination with `some()`. eg. `const hasSimilarElement = result1.some(({name}) => set2.has(name))` with this you don't have an issue with duplicate names, nor do you need `set1` and `both`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r - you're probably right - the last piece of code was an afterthought that I really didn't think too much about